# Pandas Dataframe Replace not working for sub-sentence

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have a dataframe with a column A which contains values of the form:

```
Col A

this is to be replaced
nonsense, this is to be replaced
nonsense
garbage
this is to be replace, nonsense
```

Ideal output:

```
Col A

this has been replaced
nonsense, this has been replaced
nonsense
garbage
this has been replaced, nonsense
```

I have tried:

```
df['Col A'].replace('this is to be replaced', 'this has been replaced')
df['Col A'].str.replace('this is to be replaced', 'this has been replaced', regex=True, inplace=True)
df['Col A'].replace({'this is to be replaced':'this has been replaced'}, regex=True, inplace=True)
df['Col A'].replace(regex= ['this is to be replaced'], value= 'this has been replaced')
```

Basically all standard ways to solve this. The issue seems to be the spaces in the substring. When I try to replace a specific word, it works fine.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I tried all of y'alls suggestions, they do not work. As additional context:

The exact string to be replaced is:

```
MATHEMATICS (Math 1601 & 1602)
```

to

```
MATHEMATICS (Math 1601 & Math 1602)
```

I have also tried:

```
df['col A'] = df['col A'].replace('1602', 'Math 1602')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are missing to set the result to your dataframe's column.

You can use below code to achieve your goal:

```
import pandas as pd
l = ["this is to be replaced","nonsense, this is to be replaced","nonsense","garbage","this is to be replace, nonsense"]
df = pd.DataFrame(l,columns=["Col A"])
df["Col A"] = df["Col A"].str.replace("is to be","has been")
```

Then the new DataFrame looks like:

```
>>> df
                              Col A
0            this has been replaced
1  nonsense, this has been replaced
2                          nonsense
3                           garbage
4   this has been replace, nonsense
```

Comment: This worked! Although I am pretty sure I tried this earlier. I changed the words to be replaced with a more condensed version and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col A':
['this is to be replaced',
'nonsense, this is to be replaced',
'nonsense',
'garbage',
'this is to be replace, nonsense']})
df.replace(to_replace=['is to be'], value = 'has been', regex = True, inplace = True)
df
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `replace` passing the correct parameters:

```
data = {'index':[1,2,3,4,5],'Col A':['this is to be replaced','nonsense, this is to be replaced','nonsense','garbage','this is to be replaced']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
df['Col A'].replace('is to be','has been',regex=True,inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  index                             Col A
0      1            this has been replaced
1      2  nonsense, this has been replaced
2      3                          nonsense
3      4                           garbage
4      5            this has been replaced
```